# Java heap size error while using batchDelete() on PaginatedScanList - DynamoDB

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I need to delete quite a few records from dynamoDB: **1,5mln every 6hours.**

First, I pull the records from dynamoDB to **PaginatedScanList** (because it's lazily-loaded).

Then, I want to delete them in batches so I call batchDelete() on the list.

After about ~10minutes I'm getting 
`OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` or `GC overhead limit exceeded`.
I thought that it will work thanks to PaginatedScanList.

I tried to remove records with `list.foreach(record -> mapper.delete(record))` and it works without error but it's too slow for my needs.

I can assign 1gb of heap space maximum and I can also invoke the requests more frequently.

Then my needs will look like this:
**210 000 records every hour**

That's the code I have:

```
public void deleteOldRecords(PaginatedScanList<Records> recordsToDelete) {
 mapper.batchDelete(recordsToDelete);
}
```

where `mapper` is `DynamoDBMapper`.
And the error looks like this:

```
-[pool-3-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
00:08:29
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Happy to see any suggestions.

Comment: You could try to fine tune this using -Xmx, Xms and MaxPermGenSize if you are sure that there is no endless loop

Comment: Must you load the records in order to delete it ?, Maybe you could use a `ConditionExpression` within the `DeleteItem` action

Comment: Why not just use a new table? Instead of deleting from the current one?

Comment: Or take a look at DynamoDB streams https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why not just use a new table? Instead of deleting from the current one?

Because there are more items in the table than just the deleted ones.

I researched a bit and found that **DynamoDB TTL (Time-To-Live) feature** should fit my needs perfectly without additional handling.

Thank you for your responses though.